# use subdomain fastify

Tags: regex, web, fastify

How can I allow all subdomains?
I understand that this is done for security, but I want to allow absolutely all subdomains. For my IP server
I don't want to link to the domain/server
Look at how I do it:

```
fastify.register(require("./router/router-post"), { prefix: "/api/v1" })
fastify.post('/security', { constraints: { host: /.*\.*\.*/ }, handler: /* request.. */});
```

req: `http://admin.localhost:3000/api/v1/security`

```
const start = async () => {
    fastify.listen(
        { port: 3000, host: "0.0.0.0" },
        function (err, address) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
                fastify.log.error(err);
                process.exit(1);
            }
            console.log(`Your app is listening on ${address}`);
            fastify.log.info(`server listening on ${address}`);
        }
    );
```

I'm trying to send a request now, but it's not visible.

============================================================

curl request: `curl -X POST http://admin.localhost:3000/api/v1/security`
anwser: `curl: (6) Could not resolve host: admin.localhost`

screen: [image]

Comment: If I delete a subdomain. The request is visible

Comment: Could you add how you do a request? - a curl command would be great

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon ,I updated the post, please take a look at, default logger fastify on, nothing comes

Comment: I can't see the headers

Comment: Ok, you think that `admin.localhost` should be handled by fastify - but it is your operating system that does it - you need to check your `host` file or add an ngnix container in front of fastify to make it work.

Comment: I do not want to use Nginx in the future. I just want to run it directly without wrappers. Is that not possible?

Comment: with a GET request. Everything works. Not with POST.

Comment: the `constraints` option you set filter the request based on the `host` header - so you can write it by hand in postman. calling `admin.localhost` requires the OS DNS to resolve it. https://www.howtogeek.com/27350/beginner-geek-how-to-edit-your-hosts-file/

Comment: By the way, yes. I tried that one too. Of course it's weird.

Comment: You can try to do the same thing yourself. Convince yourself

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon will you help me?

Comment: I think I give you all the spot info I could give you - (1) add nginx proxy (2) play with file host. I'm sure you can't set the `url` from fastify because it is not a DNS. The client's error is clear `Could not resolve host: admin.localhost`